# Oracle 10g to SQL server 2008/ migration

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, oracle10g, migration

We have a reasonably heavy Oracle 10G database (~ 120 GB space occupied). The database consists of tables, packages, materialized views, procedures etc. We are planning to decommission Oracle and migrate to SQL server 2008.

Can you provide your experience on this similar exercise? What is the best approach to undertake this exercise? Are there any tools available with Microsoft to implement this?

Once SQL server is commissioned, is it possible to connect SQL server to Oracle server in downstream applications?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the greatest problem will be converting your PL-SQL code.

I have not used this tool, but I would definitely investigate Microsoft's own "SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle". [1](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/migration-oracle.aspx)

You should be able to connect SQL Server directly to Oracle using SQL Servers "Linked Server" feature. That will allow querying the Oracle data from a SQL Server client, without having to make a direct connection to the Oracle instance. If you have a 64 bit SQL Server, be sure that  64 bit database drivers for Oracle are installed and configured on the SQL Server host or the connectivity will not work.

Answer (score 1):

The best work savings idea is to use Microsoft BI development studio and create Integration service project. Transformations and data analysis are excellent. Soft is free trial for 180 days...
Regards Krzysztof K

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend our DB migration tool from http://dbconvert.com/convert-oracle-to-mssql-pro.php

It is able to convert db structure and tables, but it's impossible to convert procedures and views for the moment :(

Answer (score 0):

I have used SSMA and it give you a very good starting point. I would say it will try to convert all objects and can also give you a clue what the time estimate will be if you are going to re-write some of the codes. It is free and why not have a go.

Teshome Asfaw.